# using pytz to get local timezone name

Tags: python, python-datetime, pytz

I would like to use datetime and pytz to get current local timezone name like 'US/Easter' not 'EST' or 'EDT' **No tzlocal**  module. How can I do it? all i have are like following but both are turn into 'EDT

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
import pytz
from pytz import reference
now = datetime.now()
localtime = reference.LocalTimezone()
print(localtime.tzname(now))
print(datetime.now(tzlocal()).tzname())
```

Comment: no, as I mention I do not want to use tzlocal module

Comment: The linked question as multiple answers that do not use the `tzlocal` module.